# Architecture for database-aware Application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, ado.net, repository-pattern

I'm looking for a reference implementation of the "Unit of work" and "repository" pattern for MS SQL Server or Plain old ADO.NET. But all samples are build aroud an existing context like Linq2SQL or EF. According to my understanding, these technologies are themselves almost implementing these pattern.

But how do I deal with a "plain" SQL Repository without any context and SaveChanges() methods? Is the right way to use TransactionScope? For example collect all SQL Operations in a List of commands and then simple execute them one after each other within a Tx Scope... or is this too simple?

Why am I looking for this? I have the task of building a data layer that can both deal with an ancient Sybase database as well as SQL Server (maybe additional in conjunction with a POCO based EF4 Component)

For this my Idea is to create an abstraction layer with a Repository and Unit of Work Pattern and create different implementations for each Technology.

Update:
I was on vacation the last week. Sorry for the delay. Today I built up an basic picture of my architecture for this. [link] (s7.directupload.net/file/d/2570/whb7ulbs_jpg.htm). My idea is to create a simple ObjectContext like the EF ObjectContext that exists parallel to the EF Context and is used by my repository. This context collects ATOM Sql Transactions in a kind of Stack and executes them within the Transaction within the Unit of Work part. Good idea? Bad Idea? Hard to do? I'm looking forward to your views on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't envy your task; supporting multiple backend databases in your application is going to be tricky.

Here's an example of a Unit Of Work pattern using ASP.NET MVC and LightSpeed: [link](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/12/using-the-unit-of-work-per-request-pattern-in-aspnet-mvc/)

Personally, I would use EF or NHibernate (prefer EF); SQL Anywhere supports ADO.NET and Entity Framework, so (ideally) you wouldn't need to do anything special to support that database.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Brad, I left a comment below my original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just worried about transaction scope, let me point you towards the [System.Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx) library, and its [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) object. Great class. any sql or other transaction managed system that is manipulated within the same thread that instantiated the transaction scope will be automatically added to the transaction. that way, if any part of the code fails, and throws an exception, you can just not call the scope.Complete() method and all the operations within the transaction scope are rolled back. very nice class.

Comment: yes but this only applies if you have an underlying database that supports ADO.NET Transactions I think. if you would have a myIsam mySQL database, non transactional, transaction scope would have not effect, I guess.

Comment: That is actually not true, the TransactionScope object is primarily used with ADO.NET, but it does integrate with microsofts transaction framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300805.aspx